# Phonegap + Windows 8: X-Frame-options

Tags: phonegap, windows8, cordova

I have OAuth set up for portal users as shown here:

```
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html
```

App works fine in iOS and Android but in Windows 8 I get this error:

```
APPHOST9613: The app couldn’t navigate to [url] because of this error: 401.
```

I tried using an iframe with the same url and I get the same error.

Some research suggest that this problem is related to X-Frame-options.

@metadaddy-sfdc

This is a sample response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private,s-maxage=0
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 31 Oct 2014 17:34:30 GMT
org.eclipse.jetty.server.include.X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN
org.eclipse.jetty.server.include.X-XSS-Protection:0
P3P:CP="CUR OTR STA"
Pragma:no-cache
```

Transfer-Encoding:chunked
   X-Powered-By:Salesforce.com ApexPages

Another theory is that the problem is cause because the redirect returns 401 as the error message show.

```
https://site.force.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the differences between iOS/Android/Windows in this case. It could be related to X-Frame-Options, because Salesforce blocks iFrame's from different origins. Try going to *Setup -> Security Controls -> Session Settings* and remove *Clickjack Protection* for the page you have set up (probably "non-setup customer Visualforce pages with headers", otherwise you'll have to contact Salesforce).

**Warning:** Clickjack Protection exists for a reason. Have a look at the following information: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking